# Error in using instance name as dict values and object attribute as dict keys

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create boutiqueDict as type dict which has Boutique objects tagged to different  types.
eg: b1, b2, b3 are 3 boutique objects where b1,b2 belong to "shirt" type and b3 "dress" type.
Then boutiqueDict dictionary has values in format
`{'shirt':b1,b2, 'dress':b3}`
Here is the code i've written

```
class Boutique:
    def __init__(self, boutiqueid, boutiquename, boutiquetype, boutiquerating, points):
        self.boutiqueid = boutiqueid
        self.boutiquename = boutiquename
        self.boutiquetype = boutiquetype
        self.boutiquerating = boutiquerating
        self.points = points
   
class OnlineBoutique:
    def __init__(self, *argv):
        self.boutiqueDict = {}
        for arg in argv:
            if arg.boutiquetype not in self.boutiqueDict.keys():
                self.boutiqueDict = {arg.boutiquetype : list(arg)}
            else:
                (self.boutiqueDict[arg.boutiquetype]).append(arg)
```

And this is the error i am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "hello.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.boutiqueDict = {arg.boutiquetype : list(arg)}
TypeError: 'Boutique' object is not iterable
```

I am not sure where/why it is trying to iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code above the **OnlineBoutique** is to be passed multiple instance of **Boutique** but the problem is you trying to convert such instance to list with the line

```
list(arg)
```

Obviously your boutique class didn't  override the  **__iter__()** method

And even this is against your initial idea in the first place, as what you should rather do is

```
self.boutiqueDict[arg.boutiquetype] = arg
```

Since you said the dresses in the dict should be in the format {'shirt':b1,b2}

Thus things will now look like

```
        for arg in argv:
            if arg.boutiquetype not in self.boutiqueDict.keys():
                self.boutiqueDict[arg.boutiquetype] = arg
            else:
                (self.boutiqueDict[arg.boutiquetype]).append(arg)
```

So that if the **boutiquetype** key isn't yet present then it's created, else the new value is appended to already existing Key